# How to show last version of table and figure in two columns in handout?

Tags: beamer, columns, handout, only

I show a table on one slide that updates a subsequent second slide. On a third slide I add a figure on the right.

This works nicely in regular mode, where the last slide would be exactly how my handout slide which collapses the three slides into one. Here is how it looks like:

[image]

However I failed so far, the first table is still shown on top of the second table, here the **failed result:**

[image]

I successfully use `overlayarea` to do this with figures but apparently it doesn't work with tables. Perhaps I also failed where to start the `column` environments.

```
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
    \ifhandoutmode
        \only<2>{\includegraphics[width=11cm]{figure1.pdf}}
    \else
        \only<1>{\includegraphics[width=11cm]{figure1.pdf}}
        \only<2>{\includegraphics[width=11cm]{figure2.pdf}}
    \fi
    \ifhandoutmode
      \only<2>{
        \centerline{\tiny\textbf{Fig 1.} Caption.}
      }
    \else
      \only<1-2>{
        \centerline{\tiny\textbf{Fig 1.} Caption.}
      }
    \fi
\end{overlayarea}
```

So I tried it now with `\visible` but also to no avail. This is my actual code:

```
\documentclass[
handout
]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,array,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{columns}[T,onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \visible<1>{
            \sffamily\bfseries\Large
            \begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}}
            \cline{1-2}
            \textbf{V} & \textbf{P} \\
            \cline{1-2}
            0 & 0 \\
            \cline{1-2}
            \end{tabular}
        }
        \visible<2-3>{
            \sffamily\bfseries\Large
            \begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}}
            \cline{1-2}
            \textbf{V} & \textbf{P} &\\
            \cline{1-2}
            \textcolor{blue}{1} & \textcolor{blue}{1} & \textcolor{blue}{$\leftarrow$} \\
            \cline{1-2}
            \end{tabular}
        }
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \visible<3>{
            \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[height=0.6\textheight,width=0.8\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{figures/frog.jpg}
            \end{center}
        }
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\mode<handout>{
\only<1>{}
\only<2>{}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of replacing the whole table, you can use `\alt<2->{1}{0}` to replace just the numbers on specific overlays:

```
\documentclass[
handout
]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,array,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{columns}[T,onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \sffamily\bfseries\Large
      \begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}}
      \cline{1-2}
      \textbf{V} & \textbf{P} &\\
      \cline{1-2}
      \alt<2->{\textcolor{blue}{1}}{0} & \alt<2->{\textcolor{blue}{1}}{0} & \textcolor{blue}{$\leftarrow$} \\
      \cline{1-2}
      \end{tabular}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{center}
        \includegraphics<3>[height=0.6\textheight,width=0.8\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-duck}
      \end{center}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great, however it shows the blue table on slide 1 in regular mode, whereas it should show the black table on slide 1. Also there are three slides in regular mode, where blue table is shown on slide 2, and blue table + figure on slide three. But handout should exactly as your solution.

Comment: @jay.sf See my edited answer

Comment: Thanks, you nailed it! I just used `\alt<2->{\textcolor{blue}{1}}{0} & \alt<2->{\textcolor{blue}{1}}{0} & \alt<2->{\textcolor{blue}{\textcolor{blue}{$\leftarrow$}}}{} \\` to deal also with the arrow.

Comment: Allow me a small follow-up question, how to add a caption that only displays on slide 3, resp. in the handout?

Comment: @jay.sf If your image has a caption, you can use the `\visible<3>{...}` from your original code